# I cannot solve a math problem related to scores and bonus points

Tags: javascript

The math problem I am struggling to solve says:

There is a figure which is the starting point. We need to create a program which calculates the bonus points added to the score + the total points which are the score + the bonus.

If the starting point (the score) is less than or equals to 100 - the bonus points are 5.
If the score is bigger than 100, the bonus is 20% of the score.
If score is bigger than 1000, the bonus is 10% of the score.

Additional bonus points (they have to be added separately from the previous ones):
if the score is an even number -> +1 point
if the score ends with 5 -> + 2 points

```
function solve(input) {
    let score = Number(input.shift());
    let bonus = 0.00;

    if (score <= 100) {
        bonus = 5;
    } else if (score > 100) {
        bonus = 0.20 * score
    } else if (score > 1000) {
        bonus = 0.10 * score
    } else 

    if (score % 2 === 0) {
        bonus = bonus + 1
    } else if (score % 10 === 5) {
        bonus = bonus + 2
    } else

    console.log(bonus)
    console.log(score + bonus)

}
```

When I put 20 as an argument, I expect a result of 6 being the bonus and 26 being the total points.

Comment: Your first `} else` bleeds into the if after it. So it's actually an `else if`. Also your final `} else` will only show your bonus console.log if all if statements before it are false. Probably want to delete both those else's, or put an empty `{}` after them.

Comment: Also wrong condition order in first if-else block, score>1000 part will never be executed since score>100 condition comes before and will be recognized as true on values greater than 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to have empty `else` clauses, but what really happens is that the statement that follows it becomes part of that `else` block.

This is the consequence of your choice to not end statements with semi-colons (always dangerous!). If you would have placed a semi-colon after the final `else` there would not be this problem.

Secondly, your sequence of `if` conditions will mean that the bonus will never get to be `0.20 * score`, because scores greater than 1000 will end up in the case `score > 100`.

In fact, that condition `score > 100` will always be true once the code execution gets there, since at that moment is certain that `score <= 100` is not true.

So here is a correction:

```js
function solve(input) {
    let score = Number(input.shift());
    let bonus;

    if (score <= 100) {
        bonus = 5;
    } else if (score < 1000) {
        bonus = 0.20 * score;
    } else { // certain that score >= 1000
        bonus = 0.10 * score;
    }

    if (score % 2 === 0) {
        bonus = bonus + 1;
    } else if (score % 10 === 5) {
        bonus = bonus + 2;
    }

    return score + bonus;
}

console.log(solve([101]));
```

Note that you can make this more compact by using the ternary operator. Also `score % 2 === 0` is exactly the bonus that should be added (`true` becomes 1 when put in an arithmetic expression) for odd numbers.

This decreases readability somewhat, so maybe you prefer not to do this:

```js
function solve(input) {
    let score = Number(input.shift());

    return score 
        + ( score <= 100 ? 5
          : (score < 1000 ? 0.20 : 0.10) * score )
        + (score % 2 === 0) 
        + (score % 10 === 5) * 2;
}

console.log(solve([101]));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the effort you put to explain this and be so comprehensive! your reply was very informative and insightful for me. I will definitely take not for the semi-column. Unfortunately in the course I am taking (JS Basics) we haven't covered the second method you are suggesting but I will dive into it, because it surely looks more neat... Thanks once again!

Comment: Didn't know about this, too new to the site :D It is done now.